# UM_10007 The user xxxxx in security domain Native does not exist in the domain

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to run my Informatica PowerCenter software, but I can't log into the repository. I receive an error UM: 10007, stating that My user does not exist in the [Native] security domain.

Then again, when other colleagues try to enter my account from their computers, they are able to connect without any problem. I guess the problem is local, but I don't know what's causing it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your colleagues using Native domain as well? You might need to change it to your company's domain while logging in.

Comment: Yes, they are. And also I've got no option to change the domain.

Comment: Cross check whether you and your colleagues are using the same version of Informatica PowerCenter ? Are there any Hotfixes that you have applied to your server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my version was old. Very strange, since my co-workers use the older version without problem.